# Descreasing size of a memory-mapped file in java

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

After mapping a file of size X in memory, I can not reduce the file size.

initially:

```
ByteBuffer bMapData;
RandomAccessFile rFile;
rFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
rFile.setLength(65535);
bMapData=rFile.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 65535);
```

when the process is finished, you need to adjust the file size. Unfortunately there is no way to make a java unmap, and resize the file (to less than initial size) it generates an exception.

```
rFile.setLength(2048); //generate a exception (because is memory mapped)
```

I tried to "remove" the mapping and force a garbage collector, but it also generates exceptions (but not always).

```
bMapData = null;
System.gc(); 
rFile.setLength(2048); // in some cases, generate a exception
bMapData=rFile.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 2048);
```

Suggestions to low-rezise a memory-mapped file in java?
Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be a longstanding bug in the Java mmap API (there's no unmap method), and there aren't any good workarounds. You might be able to close and reopen the file.

Comment: Close and reopen apparently work only with `System.gc()`, but in some cases generate a Exception. Without `System.gc()`the `setLength()` always generate a Exception.